# When using Parallel BeginInvoke is working while Invoke is not - c# 4.0

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke, begininvoke, parallel.for

When i use invoke inside AddListBoxItem function as seen below software become unreponsive and frozen but if i use **BeginInvoke** it works. Why is that happening ?

**visual studio 2010 , C# 4.0**

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel.For(2, 20, (i) =>
    {
        var result = SumRootN(i);
        AddListBoxItem("root " + i + " : " + result);
    });
    AddListBoxItem(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());            
}

private delegate void AddListBoxItemDelegate(object item);

private void AddListBoxItem(object item)
{
    if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.listBox1.Invoke(new AddListBoxItemDelegate(this.AddListBoxItem), item);
    }
    else
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UI thread will wait for `Parallel.For` to complete before it continues. That means it can't process any further UI messages until it's completed.

Now when the worker threads call `Invoke`, they wait until the UI thread processes the delegate before they continue. So they're waiting for the UI thread to get free, basically.

Hence, you have a deadlock - the UI thread is waiting for the tasks, which are waiting for the UI thread... `BeginInvoke` works because then the task threads *don't* wait for the delegates to be processed in the UI thread.

I would suggest that you don't call `Parallel.For` in the UI thread to start with. You'll block the UI until it completes anyway, which isn't a good idea. Do the whole thing in a background thread - then you can still use `Invoke` if you want, and while it's doing the computation the UI will still be responsive.

Comment: how can i call it in different thread ? i mean call parallel.for ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Do the *whole thing* from a different thread in the way you would anything else - from BackgroundWorker, or using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem - or even Task.Factory.StartNew.

Comment: i think tasks are better thanks for answer. now i understood why becoming unresponsive :)

Comment: I think dropping it in a Task has the best chance of not needing an extra Thread.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Probably about the same as using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, but definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are deadlocking the UI thread. This makes perfect sense, as your `button2_Click` doesn't exit until `For` completes, and *in particular*, no message-loop events can be processed until `button2_Click` has completed. If you are on a different thread, `Invoke` **uses** a message-loop event, and does not return until that item is processed - so nothing will ever be done - and `For` / `button2_Click` will never complete.

By using `BeginInvoke` you simply *queue* this work - `BeginInvoke` returns immediately. This means that the `For` can complete, which lets `button2_Click` complete, which **then** allows the message-loop events to be processed (updating the UI).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because auf the Mainthread beeing blocked in the above Click event, waiting to finish AddListBoxItem, which is waiting the buttion2_click event to return.
You shouldn't have Controller logic in your UI, so the main problem that the Click isn't calling back a logic in a different thread. 
After Implementing an thread for your logic, your GUI wouldn't block and would refresh easy in any situation.